# Centering link with image that have 100% height in a table cell (navigation buttons)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make classic navigation bar that takes 20% of screen width with 3 buttons. I want an icon on every button that should be centered vertically and horizontally. Also, this button should be clickable on 100% its size. Here is how my design looks:
[image]
But when I set height of `<a>` tag to 100% my icons are shifted to the upper border of the button. When `<a>` tag doesn't have `height:100%` it doesn't takes 100% of my table cell. Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="vertical-navigation">       
     <table class="navigation-table">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
                <tr>
                  <td class="navigation-item">
                      <a href="#1"><img class="navigation-image" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                  <td class="navigation-item">
                      <a href="#1"><img class="navigation-image" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                  <td class="navigation-item">
                      <a href="#1"><img class="navigation-image" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
    html, body, #vertical-navigation {
    height: 100%;
}

#vertical-navigation
{
    width:19%;
    float:left;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-right: 2px solid #082037;
    background-color: #023a6f;
}

.navigation-table{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
.navigation-image{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:67%;
}
table{
    border:0px; /* border="0" */
    border-collapse:collapse; /* cellspacing="0" */
}
.navigation-button
{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    font-size:1em;
    color:blue;
}
a {
    display:block;

}
.active {
    background-color: #044889;
}

.navigation-item
{
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 11px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 67%;
}
```

Here is my shortened code in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/638DL/
But somewhy in jsfiddle `height:100%` for `<a>` doesn't works. Anyway, what can I try to do this?

Comment: could you possibly have the icons as background images or you need them as inline imgs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to to have the icons as inline images and want vertical align, you can do this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/638DL/2/)

### css

```
.navigation-image{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:67%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.navigation-item a {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    
}
.navigation-item a:before { 
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;    
}
```

** What I did was basically vertical align the IMG with a pseudo element so it will always center.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
http://jsfiddle.net/UjLq2/

Basically I removed the image tags, set the A to block and it's width/height to 100%:

This makes the link use the full space - you can click anywhere to trigger it.

Then set the image from the removed image-tag as background-image:

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 11px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    background-image: url(http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 67%;  
}
```

Edit:
On your question:

"But somewhy in jsfiddle height:100% for  doesn't works. Anyway, what can I try to do 
this?"

This is because A is an inline element. As such, you cannot set neither width nor height. If you convert it to a block element, using "display: block", you can then set width/height along with everything else that can be set on block-elements only.

Comment: Can't see any image in your example at all in FireFox. But for Chrome it works. Anyway, image as background is not a solution because it scales not the same as image. Try to reduce height of your browser window and you'll see that JSFiddle logo doesn't fits the div height.

Comment: Ah yes, it's because the <a> is now empty and FireFox then thinks it's a good idea to ommit the link completely. You would need to put something - like a &nbsp; - in it to force it to render the <a>.